# Puerto de Santiago to Santa Cruz

Tags: transportation, tenerife

I'm travelling to Puerto de Santiago, Tenerife, in February and plan to attend the [Santa Cruz carnival](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnival_of_Santa_Cruz_de_Tenerife).

Looking on Google Maps this is a [1hr 20min journey by car](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/preview#!data=!4m17!3m13!1m1!1sPuerto+de+Santiago,+Spain!1m1!1sSanta+Cruz+de+Tenerife,+Spain!3m8!1m3!1d12193!2d-16.8411272!3d28.2361952!3m2!1i1366!2i666!4f13.1!5m2!13m1!1e1&fid=0).

Will there be available excursions, or bus/taxi services, which could take us to and from Santa Cruz?

How much would the likely cost of this be?

Comment: *How much would the likely cost of this be?* - Can you clarify what *this* means?

Comment: @Karlson In terms of Euros, how much would the transport cost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a bus service between Puerto de Santiago and Santa Cruz, According to [Google Maps](https://www.google.co.uk/maps?saddr=28.235155,+-16.841446&daddr=28.46041,-16.252127&hl=en&ll=28.182191,-16.54953&spn=1.03253,2.113495&sll=28.459354,-16.248887&sspn=0.016092,0.033023&dirflg=r&ttype=now&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&mra=dme&mrsp=1&sz=16&t=m&z=10&start=0):

1. Take [bus number 477](http://www.titsa.com/index.php?accion=linea&IdLinea=477) from Puerto de Santiago to Playa Americas (Estacion).
2. Take [bus number 110](http://www.titsa.com/index.php?accion=linea&IdLinea=110) from Playa Americas (Estacion) to Santa Cruz.

The trip is around 2 hours and according to the [operator's website](http://www.titsa.com/index.php?accion=articulosseccion&IdSeccion=164) it will cost around 15€.

I also assume you can just go back the same way as well.